# How can I display integer that has 2 or more digits as a string?

Tags: c, unix, integer

My assignment is to create a function that displays the number entered as a parameter. The function has to be able to display all possible values within an `int`type variable. `write()` is the only allowed function.

```
void ft_putchar(char c)    
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');

        ft_putchar(-nb + '0');
    }

    if ( nb > 0)
    {
        ft_putchar(nb + '0');
    }
}
```

I wrote this but obviously it doesn't work for integers that have 2 or more digits, how can I display them as a string?

Comment: With `printf("%d", nb);` or if you mean *convert* to a string use `sprintf()`. If you are only allowed to use `write` then you'll have to do the conversion yourself, by repeatedly taking `% 10` and dividing by `10`.

Comment: If you want them output in the correct (reverse) order, and you are "not allowed" to use a string buffer, a recursive function can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> write is the only allowed function.

A more general solution would use a loop to handle  10s, 100s, etc.  Try dividing by the largest power-of-10 and then 1/10 of that, etc.

To handle all `int` is a little tricky.  Beware of code that does  `-INT_MIN` as that is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Instead, use the negative side of `int` after printing the sign as there are more negative `int` than positive ones.

```
#if INT_MAX == 2147483647
#  define INT_POW_MAX (1000 * 1000 * 1000)
#elif INT_MAX == 32767
#  define INT_POW_MAX (10 * 1000)
#else
// For greater portability, additional code needed
#  error "TBD code"
#endif

void ft_putnbr(int nb) {
  if (nb < 0) {
    // Do not use -nb as that is UB when nb == INT_MIN
    ft_putchar('-');
  } else {
    nb = -nb;
  }
  // At this point, nb <= 0
  int pow10n = -INT_POW_MAX;

  // Skip leading 0 digits.
  while (pow10n < nb) {
    pow10n /= 10;
  }

  // Print the rest.
  do {
    int q = pow10n ? nb/pow10n : nb;
    ft_putchar(q + '0');
    nb -= q*pow10n;
    pow10n /= 10;
  } while (pow10n);
}
```

Passes [test harness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73185780/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

A test harness for candidate solutions:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ft_putchar putchar

void ft_putnbr(int nb) {
  // Your code here
}

void test(int i) {
  printf("%12d ", i);
  ft_putnbr(i);
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  int a[] = { INT_MIN, 0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11,42, INT_MAX - 1, INT_MAX };
  size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    if (a[i] > 0) test(-a[i]);
    test(a[i]);
  }
}
```

Expected output

```
 -2147483648 -2147483648
           0 0
          -1 -1
           1 1
          -2 -2
           2 2
          -9 -9
           9 9
         -10 -10
          10 10
         -11 -11
          11 11
         -42 -42
          42 42
 -2147483646 -2147483646
  2147483646 2147483646
 -2147483647 -2147483647
  2147483647 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution.

It also avoids `-INT_MIN`.

```
void putint(int nb) {
  if (nb < 0) {
    ft_putchar('-');
    if (nb == INT_MIN) {
      putint(nb / -10);
      nb %= -10;
    }
    nb = -nb;
  }
  if (nb >= 10) {
    putint(nb/ 10);
    nb %= 10;
  }
  ft_putchar(nb + '0');
}
```

Comment: I've already pushed and presented the assignment using the previous answer but thanks anyway!